# Copy multiple rows from one table to another, directly in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to copy values directly from one mysql table to another... but the trouble is, there are many rows to copy, so that sub-select statement will return many rows but the param `:order_id` is just written once.

Given that problem, I'm having trouble figuring out how to write this process:

```
# 1: Create new Order & Copy the cart basket to the Order basket
$order_id = addOrder($customer_id);
if ($order_id > -1) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_order_basket(order_id, product_id, product_name,
                                         basket_qty, basket_price, subtotal)
                 VALUES (:order_id, (SELECT (cart.product_id, product.name,
                                     cart.cart_qty, cart.cart_price, cart.subtotal)
                                FROM tbl_shopping_cart AS cart
                          INNER JOIN tbl_product AS product
                                  ON cart.product_id = product.id
                               WHERE cart.php_sesskey = :session_id)
                        )
                  WHERE order_id=:order_id;";
}
```

Here is the data I'm trying to copy:

```
ORDER BASKET            CART BASKET         PRODUCTS
FK  order_id            FK  php_sesskey
FK  product_id      <-- FK  product_id  === PK  id
    product_name    <--                 <--     name
    basket_qty      <--     cart_qty
    basket_price    <--     cart_price                              # <-- : copy to
    subtotal        <--     subtotal                                # === : join on
```

How should I go about doing this?

*Note: I'm using PHP 5 and MySQL 5.5*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can use this one?

```
INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...
```

To create the query, first make a `SELECT` which gives you all the fields which you want to insert. Then prepend `INSERT INTO <table>` and you're done.

Comment: I think I've done that? But the problem is, how to I insert the parameter `:order_id` into each row?

Comment: Okay, so I removed the `values` word and changed it to this: `INSERT INTO tbl(id,col1,col2) (SELECT ?, tbl2.col1, tbl2.col2 FROM...)` that should work right? Actually I think I should use a `:namedParam` this time because the program won't know how many times `?` needs to be inserted?

Comment: Actually you shouldn't include the brackets around the `SELECT`. Also, the `?` can only get one value, regardless of how many times it gets inserted into the database. `?` should probably work fine in your case.

Comment: Care to explain why? Because my statement actually has this structure:
`INSERT INTO ... (SELECT...FROM...WHERE) WHERE` so without the bracket there will be two adjacent `WHERE`s

Comment: You can't use `WHERE` on an `INSERT`. The syntax is `INSERT INTO ... [SELECT ...]` (without the brackets) and the only `WHERE` you can use is on the `SELECT`. Also, MySQL doesn't use brackets like PHP would.

Comment: lol, oh yeah! Don't know what went through my head there. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Look into [SELECT INTO TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html)

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (fld_id)
SELECT tbl_temp1.fld_order_id
FROM tbl_temp1 WHERE tbl_temp1.fld_order_id > 100;
```

Comment: But the `order_id` comes in as a parameter, returned from `addOrder($customer_id)`

Comment: You should be able to do dynamic queries using this syntax. Unless I am missing something....but I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, that you can do... but what about what I've got in my current query? I've written `INSERT INTO tbl_name(order_id,col1,col2,col3)` and then I put `VALUES (:order_id, SELECT(...))` and the sub-`SELECT` will return many rows

Answer (score 1):

Try using the query below; this type of syntax has worked for me in the past.  Since there is no `WHERE` in a MySQL `INSERT` statement ([manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)) I have removed that part.  Also, do not use the `VALUES` keyword when doing an `INSERT...SELECT` ([manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)).

```
$sql = '
    INSERT INTO tbl_order_basket(order_id, product_id, product_name,
                                     basket_qty, basket_price, subtotal)
      SELECT :order_id, cart.product_id, product.name,
             cart.cart_qty, cart.cart_price, cart.subtotal
      FROM tbl_shopping_cart AS cart
        INNER JOIN tbl_product AS product
        ON cart.product_id = product.id
      WHERE cart.php_sesskey = :session_id)
  ';
```

Comment: Thanks but I came to this exact answer 3 minutes ago with thanks to @tom-van-der-woerdt